# Ubuntu completely locked up including mouse

Tags: gnome, freeze, crash

I was running some scripts, and when I came back to my computer, the entire thing is locked up. Mouse doesn't move, keyboard doesn't do anything, and even the clock is stuck where it had froze.

Sure, hard restarting the system will fix it, but can this be recovered from so I don't lose progress with the scripts I was running?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your Yes/No question. If your scripts are consuming 100% of system resources, then you will likely need to wait until the processes finish (if they finish at all, as a resource-starved machine may hang if the scripts are written to act selfishly).

Answer (score 0):

If your script doesn't save any output until it has finished executing then whatever bits of partial data the script stored in temporary files is useless to you even if you managed to recover some it. Next time rewrite the script to backup some of its data periodically, so you won't lose it again.